# Sending a parameter to the render function of pdf

Tags: html, css, django, class, pdf

I'm trying in Django to render from html to pdf a monthly report that takes data from a database by month.
I need to send the selected month on the html page to the class that creates the Pdf. How can I do that?

My view class :

```
class view_pdf_monthly_report(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        push = {'month':month}
        pdf = render_to_pdf('home/pdf_monthly_inquiries_report.html', push)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

My html: how can I send the month from here?

```
<div class="text-center">
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{% url 'view_pdf_monthly_report'%}"  target="_blank">View PDF</a>
</div>
```

Thanks !

Comment: You can use form with get method and when you submit the form you can get your month from request.

Comment: Yes, this is what i do in the html file but my question is how do i send this month to the class that converts it to pdf? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create a simple form which will send month data to your view

```
<div class="text-center">
 <form action="{% url 'view_pdf_monthly_report'%}" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" value="{{month}}" name="month">
  <button class="btn btn-info" type="sumbit">View PDF</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

and then inside your views

```
class view_pdf_monthly_report(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        month = request.GET.get('month')
        push = {'month':month}
        pdf = render_to_pdf('home/pdf_monthly_inquiries_report.html', push)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```